# Cefsharp-When run 2 browsers together, browser later is exited

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I have winform application, When run 2 browsers together,later browser is exited
My later browseris exited without jump to Exception
I looked at Event viewer and saw:
Faulting module name: libcef.dll, version: 73.1.13.0, time stamp: 0x5c8499d0
Exception code: 0xc0000005
How can I fix this problem?
Thanks!

```
if (!CefSharp.Cef.IsInitialized)
                {
                    CefSharp.WinForms.CefSettings settings = new CefSharp.WinForms.CefSettings();
                    settings.CachePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + @"\CEF";
                    settings.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36";
                    settings.LogFile = "prod-cef.log";
                    settings.LogSeverity = LogSeverity.Default;

                    CefSharpSettings.SubprocessExitIfParentProcessClosed = true;
                    CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings);
                }
                if (this.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    this.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (prodBrowser == null)
                            {
                                prodBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(url);
                                //Setting browswer
                                pnlChrome.Controls.Clear();
                                this.Controls.Add(prodBrowser);
                                prodBrowser.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1, 70);
                                prodBrowser.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
                                prodBrowser.Name = "webBrowser";
                                prodBrowser.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(956, 827);
                                prodBrowser.TabIndex = 4;
                                prodBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                                pnlChrome.Controls.Add(prodBrowser);
                                //prodBrowser.LoadingStateChanged += OnLoadingStateChanged;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                prodBrowser.Refresh();
                                prodBrowser.Load(url);
                            }
                        }
                        catch(Exception ex)
                        {

                        }
                    }));
                }
```

Comment: Try upgrading to https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.WinForms/75.1.142 and make sure if you are using a 32bit version your process is LargeAddressAware https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#win32-out-of-memory

Comment: If you cannot upgrade you will need to get a stack trace see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#unmanaged-crashes-when-the-process-dies